# why do these pm2-based node processes keep stopping and restarting every second or two?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm experimenting with PM2 and specifically I'm testing the ability to have my node apps declared in a JSON formatted configuration file like the following:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "exec_mode": "cluster_mode",
      "script": "./server.js",
      "name": "proj-0",
      "watch": true,
      "max_memory_restart": "500G",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "PORT": 3000
      },
      "error_file": "./logs/proj-0_test.err.log",
      "out_file": "./logs/logs/proj-0_test.out.log"
    },
    {
      "exec_mode": "cluster_mode",
      "script": "./server2.js",
      "name": "proj-1",
      "watch": true,
      "max_memory_restart": "500G",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "PORT": 3001
      },
      "error_file": "./logs/proj-1_test.err.log",
      "out_file": "./logs/logs/proj-1_test.out.log"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I fire up pm2 using the CLI command:

```
pm2 start configuration_test.json
```

... it initially starts fine, and then every second or so it alternates between stopping, stopped and launching (when I monitor it using pm2 monit)

I checked the error logs and I see repeatedly:

```
RangeError: "port" argument must be >= 0 and < 65536
```

heres the js contained within the node server I'm testing with this (server.js and server2.js):

```
var http = require('http');
var process = require('process');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {  
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world.  PID: " + process.pid + ".  " +     process.env.NODE_PORT);
}).listen(process.env.NODE_PORT);
```

Note: I tried both process.env.NODE_PORT and process.env.port

Also, when I set the port specifically using the following and run the node process it runs fine.

```
.listen(3000);
```

Why does the port assignment appear to NOT be valid (based on what I see in the error log)?  What do I need to change for this to work?

I'm using pm2 version 2.1.5 and Node.js version 6.2.2.

Comment: you tried `NODE_PORT` and `port` but did you try `PORT`?

Comment: @david thanks, yes, I did.

Comment: @david I also did console.log(process);  and console.log(process.env) and I don't see PORT in there at all.  Im stumped!

Answer (score 0):

This may be entirely unrelated but pm2 did not work well for me until I removed double quotes from all of the keys in the json file except for the env part.

So it'd look like:

```
max_memory_restart: "500G",
env : {
    "NODE_ENV": "development",
    "PORT": 3000
},
```

Again,  may not be an issue on your system but pm2 wouldn't parse my json correctly otherwise. My example is how pm2 shows on their Quickstart guide.

Another option, and this is the route I went,  is to load your configurations in a separate configuration json and require it in your node app.

```
config = require("config.json");
.listen(config.port)
```

Doing it that way gives the added benefit of leveraging the watch capabilities of pm2. Where you currently have pm2's watch set to true, if you only wanted it to reload if a configuration changes you could set it to
    watch: "config.json"

Then if you needed to make a configuration change, you could make the change, save it and pm2 would restart the app for you. Handy if you needed to change a configuration like the port it's running on. Instead of modifying the pm2 configuration and stopping/  restarting the container you could modify the apps config and let pm2 restart the app for you which is generally much quicker than stopping/  starting a container.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are some errors in your node apps. By default, when PM2 launches your node app and it exits with an error, PM2 will automatically try and restart it. Thus you might find that running PM2 ls shows that your app keeps on restarting severally. and if you haven't set a limit in your config file, it might go on till you manually kill the process